# How to operate two SQLite databases in Android

Tags: sqlite

I have two SQLite databases, and I want to do some operation to them (such as INNER JOIN). How can I do that?

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question with a good answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824717/sqlite-how-do-you-join-tables-from-different-databases

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 separate databases there are 2 main ways of tackling that:

1)  Insert all (copy) the data into a single database, then query that.
2)  Load all data into memory and manipulate it there.

Unless I'm missing it, there does not seem to be a "Linked Server" function (like in SQL Server) which would allow you to query them in a distributed manner.

Comment: No problem, and if this solution works well for you, please mark this as the accepted answer.