# Opening database file from within SQLite command-line shell

Tags: sqlite

I'm using the [SQLite Command Line Shell](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html). As documented, I can open a database by supplying it as an argument to the executable:

```
sqlite3 data.db
```

I cannot figure out how to open a database file from *within the tool* after having invoked it without supplying the file as a command-line argument (if I, say, double-click sqlite3.exe in Windows).

**What is the command within the SQLite shell tool to specify a database file?**

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can attach one and even more databases and work with it in the same way like using sqlite dbname.db

```
sqlite3
:
sqlite> attach "mydb.sqlite" as db1;
```

and u can see all attached databases with
    .databases

where in normal way the main is used for the command-line db

```
.databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main                                                                       
1    temp                                                                       
2    ttt              c:\home\user\gg.ite
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. How do I specify which database I want sqlite to run my my queries on?

Comment: You specify the database by prefixing the table name with the database name. In the example above the prefix would be "db1", so eg `SELECT * FROM db1.tbl1;`

Answer (score 42):

I think the simplest way to just open a single database and start querying is:

```
sqlite> .open "test.db"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table_name ... ;
```

Notice: This works only for versions 3.8.2+

Answer (score 14):

The command within the Sqlite shell to open a database is .open

The syntax is,

```
sqlite> .open dbasename.db
```

If it is a new database that you would like to create and open, it is

```
sqlite> .open --new dbasename.db
```

If the database is existing in a different folder, the path has to be mentioned like this:

```
sqlite> .open D:/MainFolder/SubFolder/...database.db
```

In Windows Command shell, you should use '\' to represent a directory, but in SQLite directories are represented by '/'. 
If you still prefer to use the Windows notation, you should use an escape sequence for every '\'

Answer (score 10):

The same way you do it in other db system, you can use the name of the db for identifying double named tables. unique tablenames can used directly.

```
select * from ttt.table_name;
```

or if table name in all attached databases is unique

```
select * from my_unique_table_name;
```

But I think the of of sqlite-shell is only for manual lookup or manual data manipulation and therefor this way is more inconsequential

normally you would use sqlite-command-line in a script

Answer (score 7):

You can simply specify the database file name in the command line:

```
bash-3.2 # sqlite3 UserDb.sqlite
SQLite version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.

sqlite> .databases
main: /db/UserDb.sqlite

sqlite> .tables
accountLevelSettings  genres               syncedThumbs
collectionActivity    recordingFilter      thumbs
contentStatus         syncedContentStatus 

sqlite> select count(*) from genres;
10
```

Moreover, you can execute your query from the command line:

```
bash-3.2 # sqlite3 UserDb.sqlite 'select count(*) from genres'
10
```

You could attach another database file from the SQLite shell:

```
sqlite> attach database 'RelDb.sqlite' as RelDb;

sqlite> .databases
main: /db/UserDb.sqlite
RelDb: /db/RelDb_1.sqlite

sqlite> .tables
RelDb.collectionRelationship  contentStatus               
RelDb.contentRelationship     genres                      
RelDb.leagueRelationship      recordingFilter             
RelDb.localizedString         syncedContentStatus         
accountLevelSettings          syncedThumbs                
collectionActivity            thumbs
```

The tables from this 2nd database will be accessible via prefix of the database:

```
sqlite> select count(*) from RelDb.localizedString;
2442
```

**But who knows how to specify multiple database files from the command line to execute the query from the command line?**

Answer (score 3):

```
create different db files using
      >sqlite3 test1.db
sqlite> create table test1 (name text);
sqlite> insert into test1 values('sourav');
sqlite>.exit
      >sqlite3 test2.db
sqlite> create table test2 (eid integer);
sqlite> insert into test2 values (6);
sqlite>.exit
      >sqlite
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-06-04 14:06:34
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open test1.db
sqlite> select * from test1;
sourav
sqlite> .open test2.db
sqlite> select * from test1;
Error: no such table: test1
sqlite> select * from test2;
6
sqlite> .exit
      >

Thank YOU.
```

Answer (score 3):

Older **SQLite** command-line shells (`sqlite3.exe`) do not appear to offer the `.open` command or any readily identifiable alternative.

Although I found no definitive reference it seems that the `.open` command was introduced around version **3.15**. The [SQLite Release History](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) first mentions the `.open` command with 2016-10-14 (3.15.0).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why no one was able to get what the question actually asked. It stated **What is the command within the SQLite shell tool to specify a database file?**

A sqlite db is on my hard disk `E:\ABCD\efg\mydb.db`. How do I access it with sqlite3 command line interface? `.open E:\ABCD\efg\mydb.db` does not work. This is what question asked.

I found the best way to do the work is

- copy-paste all your db files in 1 directory (say `E:\ABCD\efg\mydbs`)
- switch to that directory in your command line
- now open `sqlite3` and then `.open mydb.db`

This way you can do the [join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6824831/2374691) operation on different tables belonging to different databases as well.

Comment: Have you tried `E:` first? Often times Windows doesn't like referencing directories on other drives without changing the letter yourself.

Comment: Yes it works, but that will not be feasible when you need to join different tables from different databases. Attached databases will no longer be attached once you exit and change directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to open a database from another drive by providing the path as a parameter, but it wasn't working. The solution is to wrap the full path to the db in double quotes. So from Powershell window in the folder containing your sqlite3.exe:

`.\sqlite3.exe "E:\ABCD\efg\mydb.db"`