# Attach DB in SQLite from Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

My code to attach a sqlitedsb to another worked fine until I upgraded to JAVA 7 ( my guess )
Howto create the syntax for attaching the database from java ? My syntax works fine using a SQL-Tool, but from JAVA I do not succeed.

My Code :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TesteAttachDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        testattach();
    }

    public static void testattach(){

        Connection connection_historymapsdb = null;
        String sTargetDB="C://temp//historydb11_maps_en.db";
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                connection_historymapsdb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + sTargetDB);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        Statement statement;
        try {
            //String sDatabasetoattach="C://temp//test.db";
            //String sDatabasetoattach="C:/temp/test.db";
            String sDatabasetoattach="C:\temp\test.db";
            //String sDatabasetoattach="C:\temp\\userdb\test.db";
            statement = connection_historymapsdb.createStatement();
            String sSQL="Attach '" + sDatabasetoattach + "' as chronica_maps_tests";
            System.out.println(sSQL);
            statement.execute(sSQL);
            String sTestSQL="select count(*) from chronica_maps_tests.testtable";
            statement.execute(sTestSQL);
            System.out.println("worked.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error Messages:

A:

```
Attach 'C://temp//test.db' as chronica_maps_tests
java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database: C://temp//test.db
    at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:275)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.exec(Stmt.java:56)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:83)
    at maps.TesteAttachDB.testattach(TesteAttachDB.java:48)
    at maps.TesteAttachDB.main(TesteAttachDB.java:15)
```

B:

```
Attach 'C:/temp/test.db' as chronica_maps_tests
java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database: C:/temp/test.db
    at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:275)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.exec(Stmt.java:56)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:83)
    at maps.TesteAttachDB.testattach(TesteAttachDB.java:48)
    at maps.TesteAttachDB.main(TesteAttachDB.java:15)
```

C:

```
Attach 'C:  emp est.db' as chronica_maps_tests
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: chronica_maps_tests.testtable
hat funktioniert !
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:115)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:82)
    at maps.TesteAttachDB.testattach(TesteAttachDB.java:52)
    at maps.TesteAttachDB.main(TesteAttachDB.java:15)
```

[image]

I tried different syntaxes (A,B,C) for sSQL, but nothing worked. How should the SQL-String be ?

Comment: Do you have privileges? try in a different drive.

Comment: Yes I have access. Already tried. Thats not the problem.

Comment: You are using single quoates ('), try using double quotes (") around the file-name (also shown in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9068549/3080094) answer). And maybe even "C:\\temp\\test.db" (escape the escape in Java code) will work?

Comment: Doesn't work. I used double qoutes with all variants.

Comment: I just reloaded my old VirtualMachine where I started the same code with "C://temp//test.db" and it works ! In the meanwhile I updated to JAVA 7 and guess that is the reason why it doesn't work anymore. I didn't change the code. I copied the same code from my older virtual machine where it worked and in my new virtual machine it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

In Java strings, `\` is an escape character.
`\t` is the horizontal tab control character, as you can see in the message:

```
Attach 'C:  emp est.db' as chronica_maps_tests
```

The correct syntax is like this:

```
String sDatabasetoattach = "C:\\temp\\test.db";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that too. This was only to show, that I tried every type of syntax. I just reloaded my old VirtualMachine where I started the same code with "C://temp//test.db" and it works ! In the meanwhile I updated to JAVA 7 and guess that is the reason why it doesn't work anymore. I didn't change the code. I copied the same code from my older virtual machine where it worked and in my new virtual machine it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

I added a newer JDBC Driver for SQLite and it worked. I guess the driver did not work correctly with JAVA 7. My old JDBC Driver was from 2011.