# Is there a way to associate items of MediaStore.Audio with additional data?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-contentprovider, mediastore

There are two requirements

- associate some sound properties, e.g. loudness or tempo, with every audio item on Android
- efficiently query audio items using these properties, e.g. get top most loud tracks

I query `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` via `ContentResolver` to get audio items and analyze their properties.

The problem is how to associate these properties with audio items - there's no additional `MediaStore` table columns to keep user data.

Current solution is to create an internal database, store sound properties there and use `MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID` as a key to audio items.

Therefore, in order to get top most loud tracks, I need

- query internal database and get item ids
- query `ContentResolver` using `WHERE _ID IN (...)` clause and get audio items

This may introduce performance issues in general case (long list of ids). Moreover, things get complicated when I want to sync internal database with content provider, e.g. remove property records for previously deleted audio items. There is no info about deleted items in content provider, so I need to compare all ids from two sources.

So, my concerns are:

1. There's no additional `MediaStore` table columns for storing user data, correct? Compare to `ContactsContract.Data`.
2. There are problems with querying and syncing internal database with content provider. Are there ways to reduce them?

Possible solutions:

- [SQLite - How do you join tables from different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824717/sqlite-how-do-you-join-tables-from-different-databases)
- [`CursorJoiner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html)