# Join on two SQLite databases python/pandas

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pandas

I'm new to Python/Pandas and SQLite.  After browsing other stackoverflow help, I've created a few large SQLite databases by uploading csv files (3GB+ each).  Want to do a join and the way I saw on here appears to not allow this.  Is there a way to do it in this construct?  Should I have uploaded multiple tables into a single SQLite database?  Thanks in advance.

Assume my databases are

```
foo.db  
bar.db
```

For a single query of a single database I have the following (works):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datetime as dt
from IPython.display import display


disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data', disk_engine)
```

Comment: first of all, i would strongly recommend you to use RDBMS like (MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, etc.) for joining such amount of data - RDMSs are designed for that. And of course you want to have both tables in one DB instance, so you can join them. I personally would choose MySQL (more powerful compared to SQLite and still free) for your task

Comment: I don't think you can SQL join across different files. The query engine for sqlite only looks at one database at a time

Comment: Thanks all.  I will go ahead and upload the csv's to a single SQLite database.  I don't think I have the rights to install a MySQL database (or others) but will check.

Comment: You can run queries across multiple databases from the SQLite command line though (eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824717/sqlite-how-do-you-join-tables-from-different-databases ), so maybe there is way..?