# Joining from multiple databbases with SQLite.Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

Is there a way to join tables from more than two SQLite databases with SQLite.Swift? The documentation only has examples from the same database.

**Note to the duplicate gurus:** This is not about how to join tables in SQlite from different databases. It's about how to join tables in SQlite.Swift, which is a Swift library that runs on SQLite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite - How do you join tables from different databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824717/sqlite-how-do-you-join-tables-from-different-databases)

Comment: @ogres Thanks but this is related to a Swift library that runs on SQLite. The two questions are related but cover different domains.

Comment: you can use raw SQL statements and achieve the same result.

Comment: @ogres Don't think it'd work because I have to create two separate connections in this case and each connection has its own ExecuteSQL method. Combining the two doesnt seem to be possible as for as I know.

Comment: @stephencelis might have an answer:)