# Querying data by joining two tables in two databases

Tags: sql, sqlite

i'm trying to get data from two databases(test1.db,test2.db) which having same table schema as

```
CREATE TABLE LoginDetails (
    Name varchar(30),
    PassWord varchar(30),
    email varchar(30)
);
```

How can I get data (email) from these two databases at a time.

I tried this

```
select
    LoginDetails.Name test1.db LoginDetails
    left join test2.db LoginDetails on LoginDetails.Name = LoginDetails.Name;
```

but not working
Please help to find out solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Never store passwords as plaintext!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite - How do you join tables from different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824717/sqlite-how-do-you-join-tables-from-different-databases)

Comment: `on LoginDetails.Name = LoginDetails.Name` does this make any logical sense to you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen I am new to SQL, i tried from stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `union all`?

```
select name, password, email
from test1.db.LoginDetails
union all
select name, password, email
from test2.db.LoginDetails;
```

Comment: getting error as below:
sqlite> select name from test1.db.LoginDetails union all select name from test2.db.LoginDetails;

Error: near ".": syntax error

sqlite> select name from test1.db.LoginDetails;

Error: near ".": syntax error

sqlite>

Comment: @SanjeevKumar . . . Perhaps you need wildcards . . . `test1.db`.LoginDetails.  Or perhaps the "db" is unnecessary.