# SELECT from multiple tables sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have 2 tables, "vector" and "vocab." I'm trying to do this:

```
c.execute('SELECT value FROM vector WHERE word IN (SELECT word FROM vocab)')
```

I'm getting the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: vocab` Of course, this is because I haven't connected to the vocab table. I only connected to the vector table before:

```
dbname = "/Users/quantumjuker/NLP/vector.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
c = conn.cursor()
```

How can I connect to the vocab table as well so I don't receive an error?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the `vocab` table actually exist?  This is what the error message is asking you to check.  You don't need to connect to a table, but rather a _database_.  Is the `vocab` table in the same database as the `vector` table?

Comment: In the folder with all my code, I have a vector.db file and a vocab.db file, so it looks like they're in separate databases.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824717/sqlite-how-do-you-join-tables-from-different-databases ... not sure about how to do it from Python.

Comment: Why is the other table in a separate database? Why don't you put both tables into the same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So SQLite3 has an ability to read additional SQLite data files.  This is done using the `ATTACH` command.  The nice thing about it is that it is used as an sql query.  So you do something like:

```
c.execute("ATTACH 'vocab.db' AS 'vocabulary'");
```

Note the `AS` aliases the database to a name, not the table to a name.  Once this is done you can run your query against the `vocab` table as well.