# How to remove duplicate record from database sqlite3 in Python3?

Tags: python, sql, pycharm

I have two databases of user's data and I need to remove duplicate records from the `db_a`, by checking one column (`login`) in `db_a and db_b` and if it found the specific `login` already exist in `db_b` it has just to remove the duplicate record from the `db_a`. To do this I thought about `DELETE Statement` in SQL, but it shows me error -

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: user_old_info.login
```

Both databases are data full. I use Python 3 & SQLite3.

```
import sqlite3

db_a = sqlite3.connect('new_users.db')
c_a = db_a.cursor()

c_a.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_info (first TEXT, last TEXT, login TEXT)")
db_a.commit()

db_b = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
c_b = db_b.cursor()
c_b.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_old_info (first TEXT, last TEXT, login TEXT)")
db_b.commit()

c_a.execute('DELETE FROM user_info WHERE user_info.login = user_old_info.login')
db_a.commit()
```

Also tried to use JOIN Statement:

```
c_a.execute('SELECT login FROM user_info JOIN user_old_info ON user_old_info.login=user_info.login')
db_a.commit()
```

The error is the same in both cases:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: user_old_info.login
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried the ATTACH DATABASE STATEMENT and here's the same error...

```
attachDatabaseSQL = "ATTACH DATABASE main.db AS checklogin"
dbSpec = ("main.db",)
c_a.execute(attachDatabaseSQL, dbSpec)
db_a.commit()

c_a.execute('DELETE FROM user_info WHERE user_info.login = checklogin.login')
db_a.commit()
```

Error--->

```
line 16, in <module>
c_a.execute(attachDatabaseSQL, dbSpec)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: main.db
```

Did it according this
[Attach A Database File](https://pythontic.com/database/sqlite/attach)

Answer (score 0):

You execute the query on `db_a`, which knows nothing of `db_b`. You would either need to use something like [attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824717/sqlite-how-do-you-join-tables-from-different-databases), or (if performance is not an issue) just separate the query by first getting the `logins` from `db_b` in one query, and then removing those that exist in `db_a` in another query.

Comment: I tried the ATTACH DATABASE STATEMENT and here's the same error...

`attachDatabaseSQL = "ATTACH DATABASE main.db AS checklogin"

dbSpec = ("main.db",)

c_a.execute(attachDatabaseSQL, dbSpec)

db_a.commit()

c_a.execute('DELETE FROM user_info WHERE user_info.login = checklogin.login')

db_a.commit()`

`line 16, in <module>

    c_a.execute(attachDatabaseSQL, dbSpec)

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: main.db`

Did it according this
[Attach A Database File](https://pythontic.com/database/sqlite/attach)

Update is on the top.

Comment: Try setting `attachDatabaseSQL` to `ATTACH DATABASE ? AS checklogin`, as shown in  the referred example.